# Juju support for Google Compute Engine GCE

Tags: application-development, juju

Is Juju supported for Google Compute Engine on the roadmap? If yes, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(This answer is incomplete and ongoing)

Support for GCE is currently in progress. Right now the target is March during one of the stable releases.

Currently bootstrap and deploy have been successful:

- https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/juju-dev/2015-January/004059.html

If you want to follow along I recommend scanning the mailing list as the developers will keep posting progress:

- https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/juju-dev/

Answer (score 1):

As of 1.23 beta release, GCE support is available. Read the release notes:

https://launchpad.net/juju-core/+milestone/1.23-beta1

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this old question and have some new information to add to the answer.

As of 1.23 Juju supports the Google Compute Engine (GCE) provider!  You can read about how to [set up Juju with your GCE credentials](https://jujucharms.com/docs/1.23/config-gce) on the [jujucharms.com documentation site](https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/getting-started).

I have been using the GCE since 1.23 was released and can confirm  it does indeed work.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, Juju does not support GCE as a provider. But be on the lookout, they may be working on it for the near future!